# The maven-surefire-plugin can not load my suiteXmlFile

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

The maven-surefire-plugin cannot load my suiteXmlFile.
The returned value of 'willUsePorts' and 'deviceInfos' is just null.
Please let me know what is wrong.

Below is my pom.xml and structure.
(my structure: ptas/src/test/suite/AppiumTestSuite.xml)

My structure:
 ptas/src/test/suite/AppiumTestSuite.xml

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.netmarble</groupId>
    <artifactId>ptas</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ptas</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/suite/AppiumTestSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>method</name>
                            <value>${method}</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>willUsePorts</name>
                            <value>${willUsePorts}</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>deviceInfos</name>
                            <value>${deviceInfos}</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

[image: My structure]

Comment: Don't provide information as image which can be text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has got nothing to do with TestNG or your suite xml file for that matter.

You are basically configuring surefire plugin to set some JVM arguments (via system properties). But the values for those JVM arguments are being referred to as properties (Since you have used `${willUsePorts}` and `${deviceInfos}`).

So Maven will try to find an entry under the `<properties>` section of your `pom.xml` called `<willUsePorts>` and `<deviceInfos>` respectively. Since there are no such values being defined in your pom file, the values for these two JVM arguments are being set as `null`.

To get past your issue, you should either be passing `-DwillUsePorts` and `-DdeviceInfos` from the command line when you run `mvn test` or you should be adding corresponding properties under the `<properties>` section as mentioned above.

Comment: "src/test/suite/AppiumTestSuite.xml" has that values.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Tests" thread-count="1" parallel="tests" preservce-order="true" verbose="2">

 <test name="test1">
  <parameter name="deviceInfos" value="LGH870DS4cd4915f"></parameter>
  <parameter name="willUsePorts" value="5000"></parameter>
  <packages>
   <package name="com.netmarble.platformQA.autotest"></package>
  </packages>
 </test>
</suite>

Comment: @Marco.Hong - Values provided in a suite xml file are not considered as JVM arguments.